# Wordpress how to get only parent posts for a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

Display only parent posts of a custom post type archive page in wordpress

My code :

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'programs',
  'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
);
$article_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if($article_posts->have_posts()) : 
?> 
        <?php while($article_posts->have_posts()) : $article_posts->the_post(); 
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $post_link = get_permalink($post_id);
        $post_title = get_the_title();
$featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID());
?>
            <p> post </p>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else:  ?>
        Oops, there are no posts.
    <?php  endif; ?>    
<?php echo "</ul>";?>
```

Result:

> "Oops, there are no posts."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters) if you only want the top level posts(i.e parents) then you would need to set the `post_parent` to `0` not the id of the current page.

Also check if you've set the `'hierarchical'` argument to `true` when you registered your custom post type.

Also it's a good idea to use `wp_reset_postdata` function after you're done with your loop!

So your code would be something like this:

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'programs',
  'post_parent' => 0,
);

$article_posts = new WP_Query($args);

echo echo "</ul>";
if($article_posts->have_posts()) : 
  while($article_posts->have_posts()) : 
    $article_posts->the_post(); 
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $post_link = get_permalink($post_id);
    $post_title = get_the_title();
    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID());
  ?>
  <p><?php echo $post_title; ?></p>
  <?php 
  endwhile; 
  ?>
<?php 
else:  
?>
Oops, there are no posts.
<?php  
endif;
?>    
<?php echo "</ul>";

wp_reset_postdata();
```

[`WP_Query`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

`post_parent` argument works the other way round :
You need this arg to find all parent posts:

```
'post_parent' => 0,  // find parents
```

As a (pretty clunky) memory aid: **Parent post is Null /doesn't exist.**

```
'post_parent' => get_the_ID()  //find children
```

Query all child posts of your current post. **Parent post has this ID**.

See this thread:
[How to query for posts (in hierarchical custom post type) that have children?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136387/how-to-query-for-posts-in-hierarchical-custom-post-type-that-have-children)